# Work with text inside variable recursively

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I have an xml message coming into template as a string param, so it can be wrapped into CDATA in node of another message (can't change this scenario).
I'm having trouble with escaping multiple sections of CDATA of message-to-be-wrapped, the one, coming as a param. I'm using following template for escaping

```
<xsl:param name="message"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <newMessage>

   <savedMessage>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($message,'![CDATA')">
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($message,']]'),']]')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($message,']]')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="$message"/>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </savedMessage>

   <xsl:value-of select="/" /> <!-- Here goes content of message, that transformation was applied to -->

 </newMessage>
</xsl:template>
```

Just splitting ending sequence `]]>` into `]]]]><![CDATA[>` and this works if there's only one block of CDATA inside. If I have >1 blocks there - resulting message becomes malformed.
 How can I get XSLT to work recursively on parameter? Or maybe look through it and replace every occurence in cycle until its length?
I'm using XSLT 1.0 with Xalan processor.

Comment: You will need to explain which XSLT processor, which XSLT version you use and tell us exactly which type the parameter has (string, node(set), result tree fragment).

Comment: Thanks for correction, added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<xsl:param name="message"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="savedMessage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <newMessage>   
   <savedMessage>
     <xsl:value-of select="$message"/>
   </savedMessage>    
   <xsl:value-of select="/" />    
 </newMessage>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will try that today